# ssh into specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

We have two compute servers A and B. The `/home` directory is shared between them and is hosted on A and sshfs mounted to B. Unfortunately, server A has become overloaded and we are unable to access it via SSH until someone resets it. The overload on A has also caused the sshfs mount on B to malfunction, so users can not SSH into server B since the mount is not responding.

I have seen numerous explanations on how to SSH into a server and change directories, but all of them require you to be able to first ssh into the default directory and then perform the cd. Is there any way to directly SSH into a specific directory (with root access, if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to log in as a user when access to the home directory hangs the login process. The login shell will automatically perform this access in order to parse login scripts.

However, you might be able to solve your problem by using a user account on server B that has a home directory outside of /home, like the root account or a special account created for this purpose.